# Parse nested indented list with Ruby by using "select_before"

Tags: ruby, parsing, recursion, slice, indentation

I want to parse the formal list from https://www.loc.gov/marc/bibliographic/ecbdlist.html into a nested structure of hashes and arrays.

At first, I used a recursive approach - but ran into the problem that Ruby (and BTW also Python) can handle only less than 1000 recursive calls (stack level too deep).

I found "select_before" and it seemed great:

```
require 'pp'    
# read list into array and get rid of unnecessary lines
marc = File.readlines('marc21.txt', 'r:utf-8')[0].lines.map(&:chomp).select { |line|  line if !line.match(/^\s*$/) && !line.match(/^--.+/) }
# magic starts here
marc = marc.slice_before { |line| line[/^ */].size == 0  }.to_a 
marc =  marc.inject({}) { |hash, arr| hash = hash.merge( arr[0] => arr[1..-1] ) }
```

I now want to iterate these steps throughout the array. As the indentation levels in the list vary ([0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12] not all of them always present), I use a helper method get_indentation_map to use only the smallest amount of indentation in each iteration.

But adding only one level (far from the goal of turning the whole array into the new structure), I get the error "no implicit conversion of Regex into Integer" the reason of which I fail to see:

```
def get_indentation_map( arr )
  arr.map { |line| line[/^ */].size }
end
# starting again after slice_before of the unindented lines (== 0)
marc =  marc.inject({}) do |hash, arr| 
  hash = hash.merge( arr[0] => arr[1..-1] ) # so far like above
  # now trying to do the same on the next level
  hash = hash.inject({}) do |h, a|
    indentation_map = get_indentation_map( a ).uniq.sort
    # only slice before smallest indentation
    a = a.slice_before { |line| line[/^ */].size == indentation_map[0] }.to_a 
    h = h.merge( a[0] => a[1..-1] )     
  end
  hash
end
```

I would be very grateful for hints how to best parse this list. I aim at a json-like structure in which every entry is the key for the further indented lines (if there are). Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error `no implicit conversion...` is essentially because you're trying to use regex against an array instead of against a string. The full error should indicate which regex is failing by giving you the line number. Can you advise that number?

Comment: Thank you @SteveTurczyn. You comment helped me. I created smaller methods and combined them to be better able to check what I am comparing.